# Detect variable type in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have an API where if you give it a directory name it will list all of the files (including directories) in the given directory. My problem is, when it comes across a folder, it adds it to a separate array, so the output is as follow:

```
{
"success": "true",
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Ajax Form",
        "tags": "jquery",
        "directory": "ajax_form",
        "readme": "Usage: $('selector').ajax_form(); More documentation needed.",
        "files": {
            "0": "ajax_form.js",
            "1": "ajax_form.min.js",
            "test": [
                "file.php"
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

Currently, to list the files in the directory, I am using this `Angular` code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in currentPlugin.files">
        <td>
            <a ng-href="/jq-plugins/{{currentPlugin.directory}}/{{file}}" target="_blank">{{file}}</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

However, when it comes across a directory, it's output is as follows:

```
ajax_form.js
ajax_form.min.js
["file.php"]
```

Here's an example using multiple files and multiple directories:

```
"files": {
            "0": "ajax_form.js",
            "1": "ajax_form.min.js",
            "test": {
                "0": "file.php",
                "test_2": [
                    "file_2.php",
                    "file_3.php"
                ]
            }
        }
```

What I want to do is when it comes across a directory, indent and list the files under the directory name. How can I get around this?

Comment: And can those directories have nested inner directories, etc?

Comment: Could there be more folders under a subfolder in your JSON structure? Could your `test` array contain both strings and arrays itself?

Comment: See, that's the problem. It could be that a user uploads a folder with sub-folders in sub-folders and files in those sub-folders. So, I need to do it blindly, really.

Comment: Ah I see, in that case you need a directive that can deal with the recursiveness. Give me a few mins.

Comment: The JSON structure is different for subfolders though. For the top files it's an object with key-pairs and then subfolders seems to be an array of strings.  Can you provide an example of how the structure looks with a folder inside the `test` folder?

Comment: I've updated the original post to reflect the changes.

Comment: According to the updated question, if a folder has no subfolders, the property is an array of strings, if it has subfolders, it's an object with key-value pairs. Is this correct?

Comment: @yvesmancera any key whose value is not a string points to an object with the files in it.

Comment: I'd have to suggest you change the JSON structure, look into one that looks like http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/ (and if that component fits your needs you could just use it)